# useContext dont pass Data

Tags: reactjs, react-context

using useContext() in my Cartcontext.js file, i tried to pass every information to my cart from produit-card.tsx. Actually, when i console.log(sendToCart()), i can see the real data. But when i go to the panier'page, the "items" array stay empty.

here are the codes:
CartContext.jsx:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';


export const CartContext = createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCartItems([...cartItems, item]);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems(cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId));
  };

  const cart = {
    items: cartItems,
    addToCart,
    removeFromCart,
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={cart}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Panier.tsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from '../components/CartContext';

const Panier = () => {
  const  {items}  = useContext(CartContext);
  console.log(items);// always stays empty
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Mon panier</h3>

      {items.map((item:any) => (
        <ul key={item.id}>
          <li>Nom du produit : {item.name}</li>
          <li>Prix du produit : {item.price}</li>
          <li>Quantité : {item.quantity}</li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Panier;
```

Produit-card.tsx

```
import { FunctionComponent, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Produit from '../prod-models/produit';
import { BsCart4, BsExclamationCircle } from "react-icons/bs";
import formatType from '../helpers/format-type';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CartContext } from './CartContext';



type Props = {
produit: Produit,
imageUrl?: string,
> };



const ProductCard: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ produit, imageUrl }) => {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [valeure, setValeure] = useState(0);
const cart= useContext(CartContext);



const goToProduit = (id: number) => {
navigate(`/produits/${id}`);
>     }
const aug = () => {
setValeure(valeure + 1);
>     };
const dim = () => {
if (valeure > 0) {
setValeure(valeure - 1);
>         }
>     }


const sendToCart = (id: number) => {
const item = {
id: produit.id,
name: produit.name,
price: produit.prix,
quantity: valeure,
>         };
console.log(item);
cart.addToCart(item);

>     };

return (
>         <div className='carte' id='globe'>
>             <img src={produit.picture} alt='fv' className='sar' />

>             <div className='contenu'>
>                 <h5 className='vam'>{produit.name}</h5>
>                 <p><span className='kak'>Marque: </span> {produit.marque}</p>
>                 <p><span className='kak'>Prix: </span>{produit.prix}Ariary</p>

>                 {produit.types.map(type => (
>                     <span key={type} className={formatType(type)} id='vini'>{type} </span>
>                 ))}
>                 <p className='groupi'>
>                     <div className='rehetra'>
>                         <button onClick={aug} className='aug'>+</button><input type='number' value={valeure} onChange={(e) => setValeure(parseInt(e.target.value))} className='inp' /><button onClick={dim} className='aug'>-</button>
>                     </div>
>                     <div className='tolo'>
>                         <button className='bou' onClick={() => sendToCart(produit.id)}><BsCart4 /></button>
>                         <button className='bou' onClick={() => goToProduit(produit.id)}><BsExclamationCircle /></button>
>                     </div>
>                 </p>
>             </div>

>         </div>
>     );
> }
export default ProductCard;
```

and finally my App.js

```
import Pajac from './Acceuil';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProduitList from './pages/produit-list';
import ProduitsDetail from './pages/produit-details';
import PageNotFound from './pages/page-not-found';
import ProduitEdit from './pages/produit-edit';
import ProduitAdd from './pages/produit-add';
import CollapsibleExample from './pages/navbar-collapse';
import Login from './pages/login';
import Page from './pages/insc';
import ProduitListAll from './pages/dropdown/AllProduits';
import ProduitListChantier from './pages/dropdown/Chantier';
import ProduitListNormal from './pages/dropdown/Normal';
import ProduitListOutil from './pages/dropdown/DropdownOutil';
import ProduitListPeinture from './pages/dropdown/Peinture';
import Inscription from './pages/SignUp';
import PrivateRoutes from './services/PrivateRoute';
import { ProduitAjout } from './components/produitAjout';
import { ProdDetfirebase } from './pages/prod-det-firebase';
import {ProduitfireEdit} from './pages/produitfire-edit';
import Panier from './pages/panier';
import { CartProvider } from './components/CartContext';


const App = () => {
  return (

    <div>
<CartProvider>
      <CollapsibleExample />

      <Router>

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/signup' element={<Inscription />}></Route>
          <Route path='/insc' element={<Page />}></Route>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}></Route>


          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>


            <Route path='/' element={<Pajac />}></Route>
            <Route path='/panier' element={<Panier/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/produitfire/:prodid' element={<ProdDetfirebase/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/edit/:prodid' element={<ProduitfireEdit/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/produits' element={<ProduitList />}></Route>
            <Route path='/produits/:id' element={<ProduitsDetail />}></Route>
            <Route path='/produits/edit/:id' element={<ProduitEdit/>}></Route>
            <Route path='/produit/create' element={<ProduitAdd />}></Route>
            <Route path='/produit/ajouter' element={<ProduitAjout/>}></Route>

            <Route path='/All/normal' element={<ProduitListNormal />}></Route>
            <Route path='/All/Outil' element={<ProduitListOutil />}></Route>
            <Route path='/All/Peinture' element={<ProduitListPeinture />}></Route>
            <Route path='/All/Chantier' element={<ProduitListChantier />}></Route>
            <Route path='/All/' element={<ProduitListAll />}></Route>
          
          </Route>
          

          <Route element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>

      </Router>
      </CartProvider>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

i just wanna map throw items in

tried to console.log() in each steps but items array stays empty

Comment: It's just a typo. You want `const { items } = useContext(CartContext);` in `Panier`

Comment: thank you, tried const { items } = useContext(CartContext); but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Greetings, I hope this will be useful to you.

As I can see in createContext default value isn't passes. Try passing default value in CartContext.jsx file

```
export const CartContext = createContext("Some_default_Value || null");
```

For further reference you may visit official Docs [Context](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

All the Best!